# Saving list template with managed metadata columns. Creating new list with the template.

Tags: list, managed-metadata, list-template

I have a list that has several columns including managed metadata columns. I'm saving this list as a template and including all the content. I'm then taking this template to another site collection and using it. It gets created fine when I use it but the managed metadata columns have no values. If I go look at the properties of the columns they're mapped fine to the managed metadata service. Any idea why the values aren't there?

Comment: How did you go? What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [hidden list](http://summit7systems.com/troubleshooting-sharepoints-hidden-list-and-managed-metadata-columns) on each site collection which is involved which may causing your problem. Managed metadata fields are quite difficult to work with in migration and I have written tons of code to manage them.

I would have taken the long route and written code which re-maps the values.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmathis/archive/2010/04/21/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-field-and-multiple-farms.aspx

describes a similar situation, except they are moving a list with MM between farms.  Managed metadata columns generate a unique guid which means it will not point to the correct metadata and the column will appear empty.

The article says to recreate managed metadata, but that somewhat defeats the purpose of creating a list template and having a metadata store...